# How to highlight a part of an image on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

My project is to capture fingerprints by pointing out the fingers of a hand image.
[image: Original image]

When to capture the index finger I want to highlight/animate similar like below:
[image]

How to do that in canvas using javascript or any other technologies?

**Update: I need a sample code to move a bar up and down over the finger to create a feeling that the fingter is being scanned.**

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific? Do you want to change the color of the finger? of the fingerprints? Do you want to get the fingerprints? Or do you already have them?

Comment: If you are asking for the basic methods: [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and [global composite operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) should get you most of the way. [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) has a tutorial on basic animations.

Comment: @Barudar : May be to move blue scanner line up and down following the finger in action. Yes, I want to take the fingerprint from a person.

Comment: @KawsarAhmed Do you need the fingerprints to be the real ones? Or just would some fake ones do? Because, if you want real ones, I think that it's a totally different story (and I have no idea how to do that)

Comment: @Barudar : Fake overlay over the finger to make the person understood that he/she needs to put that finger on the scanner.

Comment: @KawsarAhmed Then, as EmilS.Jørgensen said, you need drawImage and composite operations, and maybe  play with the opacity

Comment: Okay, I am gonna try . Thank you and @EmilS.Jørgensen. At the same time waiting for a ready code of similar operation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what steps you roughly need to take:

```js
//Get reference to canvas.
//Here i will create a canvas manually
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//Animation properties
var animationStart = Date.now();
var animationDuration = 1 * 1000;
//Overlay image
//In your case it would be an IMG element, but for this example i'll use a canvas
var overlayImage = document.createElement("canvas");
overlayImage.width = 40;
overlayImage.height = 100;
overlayImage.getContext("2d").fillStyle = "blue";
overlayImage.getContext("2d").fillRect(0, 0, overlayImage.width, overlayImage.height);
//Start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
function Draw() {
    //Determine current animationStep
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var animationProgress = Math.min(1, (currentTime - animationStart) / animationDuration);
    //Draw background image.
    //In this case it will just be a red background, but you would probably use 
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 0, 180, 200);
    //Draw overlaying image
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
    ctx.drawImage(overlayImage, 80, 30);
    //Draw highlightet part of overlaying image
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(overlayImage, 80, 30, overlayImage.width, overlayImage.height * animationProgress);
    //Draw highlight
    //You might want a blending mode here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation
    if (animationProgress != 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            ctx.fillRect(70, 30 + overlayImage.height * animationProgress, overlayImage.width + 20, -i);
        }
    }
    //Restart animation if fully progressed
    if (animationProgress == 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //Call again to loop
            animationStart = Date.now();
            requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
        }, 300);
    }
    else {
        //Call again to loop
        requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
    }
}
```